# Is it possible to deploy website into Azure windows Virtual machine IIS via CICD azure pipeline

Tags: azure, iis, azure-devops, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

i have seen a few video how to deploy the application to on-premises Windows machines with Azure DevOps.
My question is it possible to deploy it to Azure windows Virtual machine.

Is it possible to deploy the Web applications using azure devops CICD pipeline(ie, using the deployment group) into IIS of the Azure windows Virtual machine.

if i buy a SQL server windows virtual machine will i be able to achieve this.
Needed this clarification to move forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: like, srsly? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do it. Inline with 4c74356b41 , follow the doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=azure-devops